# Delete row by ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

Hello I am just learning codeigniter, here I am displaying a database and there are several rows. I made a delete function with ajax, it worked, but it had to be reloaded, how so that when I click delete, the data is deleted and it doesn't have to be refreshed.

```
      <tbody id="tbody">
           <?php
              $no = 1;
                  foreach ($temporary as $m) { ?>
                      <tr>
                        <input type="hidden"  class="form-control" name="id_service" value="<?php echo $m->id_service ?>">
                        <input type="hidden"  class="form-control" name="id_cs" value="<?php echo $m->id_cs ?>">
                        <input type="hidden"  class="form-control" name="jenis" value="<?php echo $m->jenis ?>">
                        <td>
                          <input type="hidden"  class="form-control" name="id_tmp" value="<?php echo $m->id_tmp ?>">
                          <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="" value="<?php echo $m->tracking_number ?>">
                        </td>
                         <td>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deletes(<?php echo $m->id_tmp;?>)">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
               <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
```

ajax

```
function deletes(id){
if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
    $.ajax({
       url: '<?php echo base_url();?>backend/inbound/del',
        type: 'post',
        data: {id_tmp:id},
        success: function () {
            alert('ok');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('gagal');
        }
    });
} else {
    alert(id + " not deleted");
}
}
```

Comment: By `doesn't have to be refreshed` do you mean updating the display without refreshing the page? If so, you'll need to add some Javascript to your AJAX `success` handler that removes the deleted row from the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've mentioned it's deleting on the backend or your database, you could just use jquery to delete that row on the UI. Here's one way without modifying your markup.

1. First is you add a class to the input field that contains the ID. I used **id-input**

```
<input type="hidden"  class="form-control id-input" name="id_tmp" value="<?php echo $m->id_tmp ?>">
```

2. Then use this ajax to navigate through the input fields with that class and value to delete the row. See my code on success function;

```
function deletes(id){
if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
    $.ajax({
       url: '<?php echo base_url();?>backend/inbound/del',
        type: 'post',
        data: {id_tmp:id},
        success: function () {

            // loop through all input with class id-input
            $(".id-input").each(function(){

               // if it matches the value delete parent row
               if($(this).val() == id){

                  // delete parent row
                  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
               }
            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('gagal');
        }
    });
} else {
    alert(id + " not deleted");
}
}
```

---

EDIT: use .parent().parent() as we need to refer to tr, not td

Comment: @yudafajar I updated the code, use .parent().parent().remove()

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can use `.closest()` for more details  [Click here](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> Php Code

```
<tbody id="tbody">
           <?php
              $no = 1;
                  foreach ($temporary as $m) { ?>
                      <tr class="jsRowDelete">
                        <input type="hidden"  class="form-control" name="id_service" value="<?php echo $m->id_service ?>">
                        <input type="hidden"  class="form-control" name="id_cs" value="<?php echo $m->id_cs ?>">
                        <input type="hidden"  class="form-control" name="jenis" value="<?php echo $m->jenis ?>">
                        <td>
                          <input type="hidden"  class="form-control" name="id_tmp" value="<?php echo $m->id_tmp ?>">
                          <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="" value="<?php echo $m->tracking_number ?>">
                        </td>
                         <td>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deletes(<?php echo $m->id_tmp;?>,this)">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
               <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
```

> Jquery Code

```
function deletes(id,oElem) {    
    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>backend/inbound/del',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                id_tmp: id
            },
            success: function() {
                //alert('ok');
                    console.log($(oElem).closest(".jsRowDelete"));
                   $(oElem).closest(".jsRowDelete").remove();

                //or

               //$(oElem).closest("tr").remove();
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('gagal');
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert(id + " not deleted");
    }
}
```

You can check the working example [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/2y9L54vu/)